# Downgrading Module or Downgrading to perl 5.10 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: perl, ubuntu-12.04

I have a requirement to have Storable module version 2.07 instead of latest 2.08 version installed in perl. I tried installing from backpan repository and it seems to install fine, however when script runs it still displays 2.08 version. Which makes me think that it is not picking the older version. I also think that perl 5.14 thats installed with Ubuntu comes with the latest Storable module (2.08) and I don't really know how to uninstall core module, if it is one.

So the other route I thought to take was to just downgrade the whole of perl to 5.10. That also seems to be not an easy option because Ubuntu 12.04 doesn't have it in the repository.

Any ideas how I can either downgrade perl or use older version of Storable successfully after installing from backpan.perl.org?

Thanks

Alex

Comment: Does 5.10 need to be the system `perl`, or can you use something like Perlbrew?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be flexible with Perl installations always use Perlbrew!
Go to this site, it is very easy: http://perlbrew.pl/
Perlbrew manages different Perls, and all is safely in your $home.
(Perlbrew is also on CPAN or available as .deb package, but use the website above, it is safer)

If you then add this line to your .bashrc

```
# Perl is always from perlbrew!
source ~/perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc
```

You can use the perlbrew commands on your terminal to easily switch between Perl installations.

You should not fiddle around with your system's Perl too much. Because a lot of system-packages depend on the system's Perl. If you screw this up, your system might run into trouble.

Answer (score 0):

So I was being retarded in the end. perl 5.14 WAS actually using older versions of Storable that I installed using backperl fine. But I still don't know how you would downgrade perl. Not that it matters to me, but it would be nice to know. I saw that you can compile from scratch older versions of perl, but I got a feeling that's last resort measures.

Alex

Comment: Have you checked the other answer?

Comment: apparently not :-) with perlbrew it is so easy to run different perl versions :-P